# Regex validate date and month

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I'm trying to validate the date and month in below format:

```
MM/dd
```

And now, I'm using this regex to validate:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(3[0-1]|2[0-9]|1[0-9]|0[1-9])
```

And the regex successfully validate these formats:

```
    //Below are valid dates    
    09/05
    01/01
    12/30
    10/30
    //Below are invalid dates
    11/31
    09/31
```

How to modify the regex so that it also checks the days in month?

Comment: How come `12/31` is invalid? Dec 31?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I changed the date to 11/31 instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think regex is the right way to do this. Use [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) parsing instead with `MM/yy` format and a culture that have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx).

```
string s = "12/31";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Valid
}
```

By the way, [September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September) and [November](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November) have `30` days, not `31`. That's why `09/31` and `11/31` are invalid.